# Is it possible to use Ember CLI's Live Reload with Nitrous.io?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, nitrousio

When launching Ember CLI's server with `ember serve --live-reload-port 4300` from inside a Nitrous.io box, Ember CLI's build process outputs a script tag that points to livereload.js on localhost, i.e. `<script src="http://localhost:4300/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"></script>`

The script tag seems generated by a `{{content-for 'head'}}` template expression of some kind in the `app/index.html` file.

So, is there anyway to make Ember CLI generate the script tag with a different host? I know I could plug a script tag manually but Ember CLI also generates meta tags and has the content security policy thing going on, so I'm wondering if there's a proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is not a solution in ember-cli. There is an [open PR here](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-inject-live-reload/pull/5) that adds support for configuring the live-reload host